# En Java me manda el error no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal operaciones

Tags: java

C:\users\Deborah\Desktop>java Operaciones
Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal Operaciones

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Buenas, Adrian, bienvenido al sitio. Poca gente ejecuta java desde la línea de comandos. Normalmente se usa un IDE como IntelliJ, Eclipse o Netbeans. Pero vamos, si quieres practicar así, échale un ojo a los pasos que se detallan [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16137745/2553194). Si no consigues mejoras, edita tu pregunta indicando cuales de esos pasos has seguido y qué resultado te dan